# How can I create List<custom Class> when custom Class contains List<T> it self?

Tags: class, list, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a Class with List of Lists, but can't get it to work:

```
public class Structure
{
    public List<int> variable1 = new List<int>();
    public double variable2 { get; set; }
}

public class StructureHolder
{
    public List<Structure> variable3 = new List<Structure>();
    public void InitLists()
    {
        variable3.Capacity = 1;
        variable3[0].variable1.Capacity = 20;
    }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Perform operations on values storred in variable3[i].variable1
    }
}
```

Now when I create SomeVariable of class StructureHolder and try to access SomeVariable.variable3[0].variable2 I get out of range error.

Edit1:
Fixed that, but I still get out of range exception:

```
variable3.Capacity = 1;
variable3.Add(new Structure());
variable3[0].variable1.Capacity = 20;
variable3[0].variable1[0] = 123;    //out off range error
```

Answer (score 0):

But the list in StructureHolder doesn't contain any elements yet.
You have to add eg.

```
variable3.Capacity = 1;
variable3.Add(new Structure());
variable3[0].variable1.Capacity = 20;
```

Comment: Fixed that, but i still get exception:

Comment: Fixed that, but i still get exception:           variable3.Capacity = 1;
    variable3.Add(new Structure());
    variable3[0].variable1.Capacity = 20;
    variable3[0].variable1[0] = 123;    //out off range error

Comment: but now you must add an int to the structure list. variable3[0].variable1.Add(10);

Answer (score 0):

It's because your are trying to access empty List. You just initialize the list

```
public List<Structure> variable3 = new List<Structure>();
```

but never adds some elements to it:

```
variable3.Add(...);
```

So, you need to add item first before accessing it:

```
variable3.Add(new Structure()); // adding item
variable3[0].variable2 = 100d; // accessing just added element field
```